# Output for codeception in the command-line looks weird. Encoding issue?

Tags: command-line, codeception

There are weird characters when running codeception in the command-line. How can I fix this? I'm using Windows and tested in the terminal window for phpstorm and windows cmd.

[image: weird characters in the commandline]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it was resolved but I stopped seeing the weird characters after updating PhpStorm to 2018.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

The characters you see there are ANSI colour codes.

They can be disabled by passing `--no-ansi` parameter to `codecept run`, or by disabling colours in codeception.yml file:

```
settings:
    colors: false
```